HttpClientFactory does not receive configuration
I have this setup:
services.AddHttpClient<IMyManagerFactory, MyManagerFactory>(c =>
    {
        c.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    })
    .AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(builder => builder.WaitAndRetryAsync([
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
    ]));

internal class MyManagerFactory : IMyManagerFactory
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
    private readonly IMySettings _settings;

    ...

    public IMyManager Get(string key)
    {     
        var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

        var queryString = new Dictionary<string, string?>
        {
            {"tenantId", settings.TenantId },
            {"locationId", settings.LocationId }
        };

        var uri = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(settings.BaseUrl, queryString);
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Token", settings.ApiToken);

        return new KiyohCustomerReviewManager(client);
    }
}


The client works, but the configured timeout and error policy setup in the DI do not get applied. How can i make it so the client factory takes my configured defaults when calling CreateClient()?
Edit:
My current setup is something like this;
public class BgJob {

   private IMyManagerFactory _fac;


   public Run() {

       foreach(var d in domains) {
           var manager = _fac.Get(d.key);
           var data = manager.Get(...);
       }
   }
}


The MyManagerFac gives me the right client client/manager with the right baseaddress and auth details.

services.AddHttpClient<IMyManagerFactory, MyManagerFactory> registers a named client:

The client name will be set to the type name of TClient.
...
HttpClient instances that apply the provided configuration can be retrieved using CreateClient(String) and providing the matching name.

_httpClientFactory.CreateClient(); on the other hand resolves the default one which does not have any configuration. You have several options:

Resolve the client in the ctor:
internal class MyManagerFactory : IMyManagerFactory
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public MyManagerFactory(HttpClient client, ...)
    {
        _client = client;
        // ...
    }
}


Configure the default client:
services.ConfigureHttpClientDefaults(b =>
    b.ConfigureHttpClient(c => c.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
     .AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(...))


Register named client instead of typed one and resolve it from factory with _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("SomeName");


Note that base address can be set up during the AddHttpClient call.
See also:

IHttpClientFactory with .NET


I access the same api over several domains so the baseaddress and the auth parameters in the query string change. Thats why i made a factory that creates a client on the fly. What would you suggest design wise here?

@sommmen clients are transient. Just resolve it in ctor. At least based on the provided code it should work.Or just configure default client.
